# Why my ajax sending null values to the controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I using AJAX to add and edit data to database. I have tried all the ways but the final value returning to my [HttpPost] action method is null.

ajax file:

```
function AddUpdateValue() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
            
          var upid = $('#hide').val();
if(upid=="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"){
  $(document).on("click", "#updateEditBtn",
  function(){
  var formData = {
CompanyEmail: $('#txtCompanyEmail').val(),
IntegrationName: $('#txtIntegrationName').val()             
}
console.log(formData.CompanyEmail+" "+formData.IntegrationName+" "+upid+" First for Add");
  var forgeryIdAdd = $('#forgeryToken').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: '/Integrations/AddEditIntegration',
          data: {val:formData, rowNum: upid},
          headers:{'VerificationToken':forgeryIdAdd},
          type: 'POST',
           success: function () {
            toastr.success("Data successfully added");
           },
           error: function (jqXHR) {
  toastr.warning("Data not added "+jqXHR.statusText +jqXHR.status);
           }
         });
       });
}
           else{
            var formData = {
                    CompanyEmail: $('#txtCompanyEmail').val(),
                    IntegrationName: $('#txtIntegrationName').val()
                            }  
console.log(formData.CompanyEmail+" "+formData.IntegrationName+" "+upid+" Second for edit");
             var forgeryIdAdd = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Integrations/AddEditIntegration',
                data:{val:formData, rowNum:upid},
                headers: { 'VerificationToken': forgeryId },
                type: 'POST',
               
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                  if (result.isValid) {
                    toastr.success("Information save successfully.");
                    $('#Popup').dialog('destroy').remove();
                    ReloadEmailTemplateGrid();
                }
                else {
                    toastr.error("Information saving failed.");
                }
                $body.removeClass("loading");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
            toastr.error('Request Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' Status Text: '
                    + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                $body.removeClass("loading");
                }
            });
          }

    });

}
```

Post Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [AjaxValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddEditIntegration ([Bind(Exclude ="IntegrationId")]Integrations val, Guid? rowNum)
        {
            if (rowNum.HasValue)
            {
                IntegrationsProcessor db = new IntegrationsProcessor(new MCNIDbContext());
                Integrations temp = db.GetIntegrationData(rowNum.Value);

                temp.IntegrationName = val.IntegrationName;
                temp.CompanyEmail = val.CompanyEmail;
                db.UpdateIntegrationRow(temp);
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
            else
            {
                IntegrationsProcessor db = new IntegrationsProcessor(new MCNIDbContext());
                Guid newUser = Guid.NewGuid();
                Integrations item = new Integrations();
                val.IntegrationId = newUser;
                db.AddRow(item);
                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }
        }
```

The antiforgery token, data its recieving in formData, everything is working fine it just that it returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont use this ajax

```
.....
 var formData = {
CompanyEmail: $('#txtCompanyEmail').val(),
IntegrationName: $('#txtIntegrationName').val()  ,
rowNum: upid           
};
.....

      $.ajax({
          url: '/Integrations/AddEditIntegration',
          data: formData,
         .....
```

and add rowNum to the  Integrations

```
public class Integrations
{
....
public string CompanyEmail {get; set;}
public string IntegrationName {get; set;}  
public Guid? RowNum {get; set;}
.....
}
```

and ajust the action too

```
  public ActionResult AddEditIntegration (Integrations integrations)
```